# R: Generating all possible combinations of 1 and 0

Tags: r

I am trying to generate all possible permutations of a long vector (30 elements) consisting of 0 and 1. I have tried several functions including permn and expand.grid , but none of them seems to be able to cope with this issue (due to size constraints).

Any advice would be really helpful!

Comment: What R version are you on?

Comment: `permutations()` from [gtools](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/gtools/index.html)?

Comment: Are you saying you want all `2^30` possible options? Or do you have a set number of 1s and 0s and want to keep that constant?

Comment: If you could answer my question and provide some more details on *why* you want to do this we may be able to provide better suggestions about how to solve your actual problem.

Comment: @user2357112 I am using the latest one

Comment: @Lyngbakr thank you! permutations () is almost perfect match for me

Comment: @Dason I have a vector of 1's and 0's of length 30. There are say 14 elements "1", the remaining ones are "0". I want to obtain a matrix, where each row would represent a unique combination of 1's and 0's such that sum of each row is always equal to 14

Comment: @dww It returns an error : cannot allocate vector of length 1073741824

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a multiset permutation.

```
> library(iterpc)
> I <- iterpc(c(16, 14), labels=c(0,1), ordered=TRUE)
> getlength(I)
[1] 145422675
```

The matrix is 145422675 by 30, too large to be stored in a single matrix. Use `getnext` to get the next 10000000 permutations.

```
> getnext(I, 10000000)
```

You could repeat the above 15 times in order to get all the permutations.

Answer (score 0):

a simple and naive implementation...

```
system.time(x <- combn(30,14))
# user  system elapsed 
# 252.42    2.17  254.98 

pryr::object_size(x)
# 8.14 GB

dim(x)
# [1]        14 145422675

system.time(
  apply(x[,1:1e6],2,function(index){
    V <- rep(0,30)
    V[index] <- 1
    return(V)
  } )
)
# user  system elapsed 
# 8.23    0.24    8.52
```

I would not run the entire `x` unless there is a good reason...